# Intercepting sharepoint open document request

Tags: sharepoint, request, httpmodule, intercept

I am currently trying to intercept the request SharePoint sends for viewing a document in a document library with a HttpModule to do custom processing.

Unfortunatly, SharePoint seems to send the requests through an ActiveX control (OpenDocuments) and the HttpModule does not see those requests.

What i'm trying to do here is:
1- intercept the request
2- Verify if current user has permission to open documents (custom permission level).
3- If user doesn't have permissions, transfer request to acces denied page.

My question is: Is there any way to do this (with or without the httpmodule)?

Current Code for reference:

```
public class ViewOnlyModule : IHttpModule
{
    HttpApplication App;

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        App=context;
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(PreventAccessToFile);
        //context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(PreventAccessToFile);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    private void PreventAccessToFile(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code    

    }
}
```

Comment: Sharepoint would trim the linked to the document if they did not have permission, so not sure why you would need todo this